Using a fine-tuned model in Spring AI (Vertex AI)
I have created a finetuned model on Vertex AI and I would like to use this model in my RAG application. Does Spring AI support fine-tuned models? Or is it only these models you can use:
Supported Vertex AI Gemini Chat model to use include the (1.0 ) gemini-pro, gemini-pro-vision (deprecated) and the new gemini-1.5-pro-001, gemini-1.5-flash-001 models.
Tried specifying my model name in the application.properties but it defaults to 'gemini-flash-001' when I debug.

I know you can use fine-tuned models in Ollama, but I'm not sure if it is supported for Google or Azure fine-tuned models.
